# Moving from Drupal 6 to 7 - trailing slashes and content views

Tags: 7, views

I have a site which I need to move from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.

I heard that Drupal 7 doesn't support trailing slashes (URLs like `http://example.com/folder/`)

I also heard that to move the content I'll have to manually remap some CCK fields of the posts in the previous version to the fields in the new one. Is it true?

Finally – is there a reliable automated way to move all the content or if I can afford it I should try to move all the pages manually?

Thank you and let me know!

Comment: Hello and welcome. You asked many questions in one. Most of them was answered here already, I believe. Do you have a *specific* question? Because we can't really provide you with upgrade manual. There are manuals like that on https://drupal.org already.

Comment: You can use Migration API to move content from d6 to d7.